# raku, library was not found

Tags: perl, shared-libraries, raku

I was trying to execute this program in `Raku` but I got an error below:
How should I provide `raku` with the `perl` library there; what to copy where ?

```
use Math::BigInt;
$i = Math::BigInt->new($string);
use Math::BigInt ':constant';
print 10**121900;
```

[image]

> Could not find `Math::BigInt` in

**EDIT**

I have failed to run `zef` **after installing it**:

[image]

> Failed to stat file: no such file or directory

**EDIT**

[image]

> Failed to stat file: no such file or directory

Comment: First question: why would you want to use `Math::BigInt`? Integers in Raku are bigints by default.  Just executing `print 10**121900` will give you a `1` followed by `121900` zeroes.

Comment: Second question: to be able to use Perl modules from Raku, you **must** install the `Inline::Perl5` module first: `zef install Inline::Perl5`.  After that, you can use modules with the `from<Perl5>` adverb.  In your example: `use Math::BigInt:from<Perl5>`.

Comment: Your first answer has helped, it really works. For your second comment, I use `Cygwin` which doesn't know anything like `zef`. Could you give me a link to download `InLine::Perl5` ?

Comment: Then it's probably wiser to first download `zef` (`git clone https://github.com/ugexe/zef.git` and follow the README), and then do `zef install Inline::Perl5`  :-)

Comment: @user2925716 What link did you visit to get Rakudo before you installed it?

Comment: cygwin is 1990s tech and it never worked really well. better use WSL2 which gives you a real linux kernel, not a bolted on stopgap

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I had to first install `git`. Now I have `zef` but it writes an error, please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I got **nothing** from executing `zef`: `hynek0@hynek /cygdrive/c/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/A3/rakudo-moar-2021.05-01-win-x86_64-msvc/share/perl6/site/bin
$ ./zef install Inline::Perl5
===> Searching for: Inline::Perl5` The program just hangs on.

Comment: Meh, I think Raku is just broken on Cygwin :-(   I don't think we have a CI environment set up for it :-(

Answer (score 6):

`Math::BigInt` is a Perl module

1. `Inline::Perl` needs to be installed in Raku
2. `Math::BigInt` needs to be installed in Perl
3. You need to tell Raku that it is a Perl module rather than the default of being a Raku module

```
use Inline::Perl5;
use Math::BigInt:from<Perl5>;

my $string = "121900";
my $i = Math::BigInt->new($string);

say 10**$i;
```

(Untested as I am away from my computer)

Of course that is rather pointless as Raku already supports large integers.

```
say 10**121900;
```

Comment: There appears to be an issue even loading `Math::BigInt` through the `Inline::Perl5` bridge.